# My Django site is not loading in Elasticbeanstalk due to settings.py not being found

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't get my Django website to load.  These are my error messages from the logs:

```
get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699497 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699503 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699507 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699512 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699515 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699520 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699523 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699528 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699530 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699535 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699538 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699543 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699548 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699553 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Jan 07 23:38:51.699567 2019] [:error] [pid 6456] [remote 74.71.99.135:244] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecs_site.settings'
```

Here is the directory structure for the top level directory (ecs_site):

```
total 272
-rw-r--r--   1 chauncey  staff    97B Jan  6 21:02 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  14 chauncey  staff   476B Jan  4 18:11 pages
-rwxr-xr-x   1 chauncey  staff   806B Mar 22  2018 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  10 chauncey  staff   340B Jan  4 18:05 ecs_site
-rw-r--r--   1 chauncey  staff   128K Mar 22  2018 db.sqlite3
```

Here is the directory structure for the `/ecs_site/ecs_site` directories:

```
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff   394B Jan  7 18:07 wsgi.py
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff   812B Mar 22  2018 urls.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 chauncey  staff   102B Mar 23  2018 templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 chauncey  staff    68B Mar 23  2018 static
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff   3.6K Jan  6 21:09 settings.py
drwxr-xr-x  6 chauncey  staff   204B Jan  1 20:43 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff     0B Mar 22  2018 __init__.py
```

This is the directory structure of the `./ecs_site/pages` directory:

```
total 56

-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff   7.1K Jan  4 19:53 views.py
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff   153B Jan  4 18:45 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff    60B Mar 22  2018 tests.py
drwxr-xr-x  5 chauncey  staff   170B Apr 14  2018 templatetags
drwxr-xr-x  4 chauncey  staff   136B Apr  3  2018 templates
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff    57B Mar 22  2018 models.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 chauncey  staff   136B Mar 22  2018 migrations
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff    85B Mar 22  2018 apps.py
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff    63B Mar 22  2018 admin.py
drwxr-xr-x  8 chauncey  staff   272B Jan  4 19:53 __pycache__
-rw-r--r--  1 chauncey  staff     0B Mar 22  2018 __init__.py
```

This is the `/.ebextensions/django.config` file:

```
option_settings:
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
     DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE: "ecs_site.settings"
     PYTHON_PATH: "/opt/python/current/ecs_site/ecs_site:$PYTHONPATH"
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
     WSGIPath: "ecs_site/ecs_site/wsgi.py"
```

Here is my `wsgi.py` file (fyi):

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecs_site.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here's manage.py:

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ecs_site.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` setting in your `django.config` file seems to be going too deep. The second level `ecs_site` directory is a package, and so the `PYTHONPATH` should point to the directory above, in order that the `ecs_site.settings` module can be resolved:

```
PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/ecs_site:$PYTHONPATH"
```

Also, ensure that the variable is named `PYTHONPATH` and not `PYTHON_PATH`.

Comment: Even if the `settings.py` file is in the `ecs_site\ecs_site` directory?

Comment: Yes because the qualified name of the settings is `ecs_site.settings`, which means the PYTHONPATH should point at the directory containing the `ecs_site` package, not at the `ecs_site` package itself.

Comment: I've just noticed that you've named the environment variable `PYTHON_PATH` when it should be `PYTHONPATH` (no underscore). I've added a note to the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I was lost in this for a while.  I appreciate you seeing my typo and not making me feel like an idiot for it.